# how do I define multiple model classes inside ODataModelBuilder

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have one `OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API` which is having two separate models

ModelVer1.Customer.cs

```
int ID;
string Name;
```

ModelVer2.Customer.cs

```
int ID;
string Name;
string Address;
```

webapiconfig.cs

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<ModelVer1.Customer>("Customers");
          // If I use below get error:
          // The entity set 'Customers' was already configured with a different EntityType ('Customer'). Parameter name: entityType
            builder.EntitySet<ModelVer2.Customer>("Customers");


            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "demo/api",
                model: builder.GetEdmModel());


            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerSelector), new CustomControllerSelector(config));


        }
```

But getting error :

> The entity set 'Customers' was already configured with a different
>   EntityType ('Customer').
>                    Parameter name: entityType

What should be done?

> I guess i need to do something like `model: builder.GetEdmModel()`
>   need to generate this model dynamically which gets all entity model
>   classes like ModelVersion1.Customer and ModelVersion2.Customer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a different alias / name.

Instead of

```
builder.EntitySet<ModelVer1.Customer>("Customers");
builder.EntitySet<ModelVer2.Customer>("Customers");
```

Use

```
builder.EntitySet<ModelVer1.Customer>("Customers");
builder.EntitySet<ModelVer2.Customer>("CustomersV2");
```

Comment: it works fine strange how come as `CustomersV2` it is nothing but name right ? how it is pointing to `Customer` table? m bit new to odata please elaborate thanks

Comment: The alias is referred to in the URI, ie: myDomain/Customers/. If you use the same alias then the oData controller no longer knows which entity it needs perform operations against or query against.

Comment: yes I'm passing version number in header and mu custom selector does routing thats why name does not matter is it ? name is anything i can give but my custom selector does routing stuff for me and domain model is already define correctly so it works , right ?

Comment: @Neo - From my understanding which is based on how I have implemented oData in my projects over the past year.   The entity configuration it is added to a dictionary where the key is the name that you pass. That is then accessed when you access a route and the default convention is that the route name is used to find the correct entity type using that dictionary. I did find this article very useful though in avoiding some common pitfalls: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidhardin/archive/2014/12/17/web-api-odata-v4-pitfalls-and-lessons-learned.aspx